# Craco build fails, taking aliased folder as external package

Tags: reactjs, webpack, alias, create-react-app, craco

I'm using craco and craco-alias to implement aliases for imports in my Create React App project.
Followed instructions in https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco/README.md#installation and https://github.com/risenforces/craco-alias#readme
I configured package.json to use craco instead of react-scripts for starting dev server, tests and production build

```
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "lint:css": "stylelint './src/**/*.css'",
    "lint:js": "eslint 'src/**/*.js'",
    "test:w": "craco test --watch",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
...
```

Then I created jsconfig.json file w aliases paths

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@components": ["components/*", "components"],
      "@constants": ["constants/*", "constants"],
      "@assets": ["assets/*", "assets"],
      "@store": ["store/*", "store"],
      "@utils": ["utils/*", "utils"]
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "coverage"]
  }
```

And craco.config.js file, which uses craco-alias plugin

```
/* craco.config.js */
const CracoAlias = require('craco-alias');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoAlias,
      options: {
        baseUrl: './src',
        source: 'jsconfig',
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I'm using aliases for imports in my app like this

```
// root index.js file
...

import Layout from '@components/Layout';
import store from '@store'; // this line causes error on CI build


function App() {
  return (
    <Layout>
     /* inner components */
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Everything works fine (aliased imports works on dev-server, in jest tests and even if I serve locally built project) until I push it to github repo. That repo has configured github actions to build and test project on remote server and it fails with error on build step, after installing all packages.

```
Run yarn build
yarn run v1.22.4
$ craco build
Creating an optimized production build...
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
Cannot find module: '@store'. Make sure this package is installed.

You can install this package by running: npm install @store.


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Could somebody help me understand what wrong with my code? Why craco or webpack expect '@store' to be external package instead of aliased import of internal module?

Answer (score 3):

In my case problem wasn't in craco or webpack, but in my previous actions and OS filesystem differences. I'm using Windows 10 and WSL in VS Code terminal. So before I use '@' symbol for aliases I tried to use CamelCase for my folders and renamed it via windows explorer (because for me it was simpler to close VSCode and rename files via explorer than to open new bash terminal in new VSCode window after closing opened files).

Then I prefer to use '@' symbol and rename folders back to lowercase. I configured aliases and pushed changes to remote github repo, where CI actions were run. When CI was running actions it can't find 'store' folder (because previously I renamed it to 'Store' and it was last saved path to folder in git), so it tried to find external package named 'store'.

To fix this I change git config to stop ignoring namecasing for my folder by running command `git config core.ignorecase false`. Git history was updated, I push it to remote repo and CI actions succeeded.

Comment: Had this exact same issue and your answer worked. I changed the casing of a folder '/router' to '/Router' and git ignored it, but my files had the correct new casing `import from '@components/Router'. After setting ignorecase to false and deleting the duplicate folders the build was successful in the docker container. Thanks for answering your own question, I was pulling my hair out before finding it.